# How can I see processes being run by another instance of root on my Beaglebone

Tags: linux, debian, dd

I am installing a Raspbian Linux image onto an sd card inserted into my BeagleBone Black.  I will use this later in my Raspberry Pi.

To do this, I am using the dd command from my MacBook Pro (via ssh).

```
dd if=/Users/user/Downloads/2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian.img | ssh root@192.168.7.2 "dd of=/dev/mmcblk0"
```

It initially looks like it is working, as executing the command gives me:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 7

BeagleBoard.org BeagleBone Debian Image 2014-04-23

Support/FAQ: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian
```

In the mean time I can ssh to my beaglebone through another Terminal window, again logging in as root `ssh 192.168.7.2 -l root`.  How can I now monitor the copying of the .img file to /dev/mmcblk0 via the dd command?

Unfortunately it does not look like the sd card is being filled (/dev/mmcblk0p1 is using 15K after well over 5 minutes):

```
root@beaglebone:/dev# df -ah
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  3.4G  1.5G  1.9G  44% /
sysfs                                                      0     0     0    - /sys
proc                                                       0     0     0    - /proc
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
devpts                                                     0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                                                   100M  624K   99M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/88d655b6-c63d-4922-9b0e-340b5ece0b8c  3.4G  1.5G  1.9G  44% /
tmpfs                                                   249M     0  249M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                   249M     0  249M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup                                                     0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
cgroup                                                     0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup                                                     0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup                                                     0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
systemd-1                                                  0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
debugfs                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tmpfs                                                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
mqueue                                                     0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
securityfs                                                 0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
fusectl                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
/dev/mmcblk1p1                                           96M   74M   23M  77% /boot/uboot
binfmt_misc                                                0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
/dev/mmcblk0p1                                           15G   32K   15G   1% /media/6461-6136
root@beaglebone:/dev#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you found the answer already.  But another possibly easier to remember one is

```
killall -USR1 dd
```

(which would signal every dd process, which there is usually only one)

The output shows up on the original window because you are sending a signal to the existing 'dd' command, and dd has a feature where it dumps progress to stderr when it gets that signal.

I also want to point out it appears you are overwriting a partition WHICH IS CURRENTLY MOUNTED.  That's a very bad thing, and you're likely to corrupt your filesystem like that.  Always un-mount a partition before overwriting it.

Also, you can sometimes speed up dd by giving it a larger block size (and let ssh pull directly from the file).  For instance, change the command to

```
ssh root@192.168.7.2 "dd of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M" < /Users/user/Downloads/2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

Answer (score 1):

This command worked in the end, executed on my beaglebone as root:

```
pkill -USR1 -n -x dd
```

I could run the command over and over again and it would indeed update (slow transfer).

Interestingly, the update would appear on the *other* Terminal window (i.e. the one executing the dd command):

```
Debian GNU/Linux 7

BeagleBoard.org BeagleBone Debian Image 2014-04-23

Support/FAQ: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian
39136+0 records in
39136+0 records out
20037632 bytes (20 MB) copied, 5.6016 s, 3.6 MB/s
89376+0 records in
89376+0 records out
45760512 bytes (46 MB) copied, 12.3178 s, 3.7 MB/s
205152+0 records in
205152+0 records out
105037824 bytes (105 MB) copied, 27.7496 s, 3.8 MB/s
296608+0 records in
296608+0 records out
151863296 bytes (152 MB) copied, 40.7469 s, 3.7 MB/s
361184+0 records in
361184+0 records out
184926208 bytes (185 MB) copied, 49.3917 s, 3.7 MB/s
432672+0 records in
432672+0 records out
221528064 bytes (222 MB) copied, 58.9498 s, 3.8 MB/s
648529+0 records in
648529+0 records out
332046848 bytes (332 MB) copied, 88.3797 s, 3.8 MB/s
702289+0 records in
702289+0 records out
359571968 bytes (360 MB) copied, 103.606 s, 3.5 MB/s
987329+0 records in
987329+0 records out
505512448 bytes (506 MB) copied, 194.866 s, 2.6 MB/s
991001+0 records in
991001+0 records out
507392512 bytes (507 MB) copied, 197.19 s, 2.6 MB/s
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool I use to monitor in progress file transfers (i.e. I used to track the copying of ROMS from sdcard to USB drive in RetroPie) that does exactly that is, appropriately enough, `progress`.

It is a "Tiny, Dirty, Linux-and-OSX-Only C command that looks for `coreutils` basic commands (`cp`, `mv`, `dd`, `tar`, `gzip`/`gunzip`, `cat`, `rsync`, etc.) currently running on your system and displays the percentage of copied data."

You'll probably have to install it (`sudo apt install progress`) then run as `sudo`.

I recommend adding the `-m` command to have it continuously monitor and update:

```
sudo progress -m
```